# Euclidean distance between the two points using vectorized approach

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have two large `numpy` arrays for which I want to calculate an Euclidean Distance using `sklearn`. The following MRE achieves what I want in the final result, but since my RL usage is large, I really want a vectorized solution as opposed to using a `for` loop.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

n = 3
sample_size = 5

X = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(sample_size, n))
Y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(sample_size, n))

lst = []

for f in range(0, sample_size):
    ed = euclidean_distances([X[f]], [Y[f]])
    lst.append(ed[0][0])

print(lst)
```

Comment: You specified that you want to use `sklearn` to compute the distances. Is that really necessary? If so, then I think you're stuck with what they gave you.  If not, then it's not clear what the trouble would be in writing your own how you want.  Euclidean distance is not a complicated function.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting what you're trying to accomplish, but does `euclidean_distances(X, Y).diagonal()` not do what you want? If not, could you explain how that differs from what you do want?

Comment: `np.sqrt(((X - Y)**2).sum(1))`?

Comment: @Brick yeah I know, it is for an online class and therefore I'm assuming we're going to build on the complexity of it.

Comment: @Brian: that works! Can you post as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: @MustadaAydin's solution would have worked under normal circumstances, but I wanted to stick with the assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`euclidean_distances` computes the distance for each combination of X,Y points; this will grow large in memory and is totally unnecessary if you just want the distance between each respective row.  Sklearn includes a different function called `paired_distances` that does what you want:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances
d = paired_distances(X,Y)
# array([5.83095189, 9.94987437, 7.34846923, 5.47722558, 4.        ])
```

If you need the full pairwise distances, you can get the same result from the diagonal (as pointed out in the comments):

```
d = euclidean_distances(X,Y).diagonal()
```

Lastly: arrays are a numpy type, so it is useful to know the numpy api itself (prob. what sklearn calls under the hood).  Here are two examples:

```
d = np.linalg.norm(X-Y, axis=1)
d = np.sqrt(np.sum((X-Y)**2, axis=1))
```